# Inner case statement is throwing an error when trying to sum the values

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select sum(t.amount)
from
(select yearquarter,
       (case when sum(case when type not in (3, 4) then 1 else 0 end) = 0
             then sum(amount)
             else sum(case when type not in (3, 4) then amount else 0 end)
        end)
from t
where status = 'A'
group by yearquarter)t;
```

Need to sum up "Amount" from inner case statement but Getting an error

Comment: What are you trying to do here actually?

Comment: error:Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 13
No column name was specified for column 2 of 't'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'amount'.

Comment: I am trying to add the two case "amounts" from case statement into one

Comment: The error is as clear as it gets, you need to add an alias to the result of the outer case expression.

Comment: In your first line you are summing up a column named `amount` in `t`. There is no column named `amount` in `t`. You need to add an alias ` (Your big case statement) AS amount` in your subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't name the amount column in your t subquery.

```
select sum(t.amount)
from
(select yearquarter,
       (case when sum(case when type not in (3, 4) then 1 else 0 end) = 0
             then sum(amount)
             else sum(case when type not in (3, 4) then amount else 0 end)
        end) AS amount
from t
where status = 'A'
group by yearquarter)t;
```

Comment: Should make the outer alias a different name to avoid confusion. +1 from me.